# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' React native

Tags: react-native

Code so far :

```
fetch('http:/example.com',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Id: this.state.TextInputId
      })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        Snackbar.show({
          title: responseJson,
          duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
```

Produces the error: `Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' React native`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you try to parse something that is not JSON, but a string beginning with `<`, so XML data (HTML probably). Try to put a `console.log(response);` right before `response.json();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token'<' - react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a issue related to react-native but related to your response.
You're getting something like '<' in response which cannot be converted to JSON. Try with response.text()