# [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '']

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo

I just want to map a JSON data in react native error, but I am getting error that "[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '﻿']" after parsing it with JSON.parse.

```
    axios.get("http://www.upclass.com.hk/api.php?apicall=getcustomer").then((e) => {
          var res = JSON.parse(e.data)
          console.log("New Data =>", res);
          this.setState({
                data: res
                });
    });
```

This is the JSON data

```
{
"id": "D6C9C876-CDA2-4C27-85BF-276D3035D762",
"fullname": null,
"username": null,
"email": "mohssssin@gmail.com",
"areaid": null,
"aid": null,
"mobile": "123456",
"photoid": null,
"imagepath": null,
"lang": "zh",
"custgroup": "P         ",
"IsVolunteer": null,
"notification": "Y",
"createdate": "2021-03-26 19:05:02.290",
"updatedate": null,
"otherarea": null
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native

Comment: `e.data` is already an object. You don't need to parse it with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @derpirscher, But I cannot map it using this.state.data.id

Comment: @SuhailKakar - Then put a breakpoint on the first line of your fulfillment handler and look at `e.data` in the debugger and see what you're getting back.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, In postman it is fine, Even I browser I am getting correct data, but When I add to my code I get an "?" at the beginning of response

Comment: @SuhailKakar - Don't look at it in postman. Look at it in your browser, with the code paused on the first line of your fulfillment handler. Browsers != postman.

Answer (score -3):

Try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject instead of Parse. [You can check here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Comment: Quite unlikely that using a .NET library like NewtonSoft.Json will work in javascript ...