# Users start receiving `Unrecognized token "<"` after deploys

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, create-react-app

I have a create react app hosted on AWS, served by nginx. When launching new deploys, some users are experiencing the above error. Opening the page in a new browser fixes the issue. I'm wondering if it could be a caching issue?

Has anyone had any similar experiences?

Comment: Do you have an idea where that error is occurring?  Can you post the code where the error is happening?

Comment: There are approximately a thousand possible causes of that very generic error. You'll need to show some code and ask something more specific. See [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native. Good luck.