# ionic capacitor http request doent work on simulate ios device

Tags: angular, http, ionic4, capacitor

when i send an http request it works fine on the browser (using ionic serve) but when i build ios and android versions using capacitor i get the attached error in the console
error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
[image: error]
here is my code
[image: code]

when i call request i got the following error while the request returns 200 normally
[image]

Comment: The HTML isn't a JSON

Comment: to clarify the requests are coming from spring boot backend

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using doesn't reply with JSON. If it should, you seems to miss something because it answer with HTML code.

I suggest you to see the HTML code which will tell you what is wrong.

The error appear because the JSON should be like that:

```json
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

You can try to change the header in your request by adding this:

```
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

You can get more informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50837479/10952503) for example.