# How to solve warning "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'"?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, http, fetch-api

I am writing an app with React Native for IOS device, with Django server (Python).
I saw that this question was asked many times - but non of the answers worked for me, so maybe someone can help.

This is my code:

```
  let url = base_url + eventManager(id);
  let request = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  };
  await fetch(url, request, { timeout: 2000 })
    .then(async (res) => {
      const data = await res.json();
    ....
   }
```

I got an warning 'JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<''
I already tried

- replacing res.json() with res.text()
- removing content-type header
- removing the timeout argument
- change the handle promise like that:

  ```
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(resJson => {
             ...
         }
  ```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging the response? It looks like it contains HTML, not JSON

Comment: this may help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native

Comment: or check if the JSON is valid proper brackets closed and doesn't have unwanted spaces

Comment: @Nick `res.text():  Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}`
That is the log of res.text() - what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This most probably means the response you are getting from the webserver is not a JSON object, instead, it is an HTML document. Do a console.log of the output you get from `res.text()` and the rest should be easy to figure out.
Most probably the endpoint you are requesting is wrong, for example in the case of express.js if you request an endpoint that does not exist it would respond with this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose it is similar in Django as well, also if you are saying that you have tried using the response.text() method already, then maybe make sure that the error originates from the part of code you suspect.

Comment: ``` res.text():  Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}``` That what I got when I logged the res.text() - what should I do?

Comment: `res.text()` returns a promise, use the `.then` or `await` syntax