# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' while requesting/posting data with react-native and django

Tags: python, reactjs, json, django, react-native

I just started building a react-native frontend and a Django backend application and I tried making requests from react native to the Django server but I got "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'"
I am assuming that this is caused by an error in the API code but I could not figure it out.
here's my code:

views.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from .serializers import UserSerializer, ProfileSerializer
from .models import Profile
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication 
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, BasePermission
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer



class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer


@csrf_exempt   
def login(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        valid = False
        
        if 'username' in request.data:
            username = request.data['username']
            password = request.data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                valid = True
            else:
                valid = False
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        valid = True
        data = {
                'valid': valid,
            }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

login.js-

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView  } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';



export default function Login(props) {

  const message = props.navigation.getParam('message', null)
  const [ valid, setValid ] = useState("")
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("")
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("")

  const val = () => {
    if(valid.valid) {
      props.navigation.navigate("MovieList")
    } else {
      var message = True
      props.navigation.navigate("Login", {message: message})
    }
  }

  const check = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.5.213:8000/home/login/', {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
        
     }
     })
     .then( res => res.json())
     .then( jsonRes => 
      setValid(jsonRes)
      )
     .catch( error => console.log(error))
     };

  const log = () => {

    fetch(`http://192.168.5.213:8000/home/login/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": 'application/json'
         },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}),
  })
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( res => {
    () => check()
    

  })
  .catch( error => console.log(error))
  


  



  }

  const sign = () => {

    props.navigation.navigate("Signup")

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
      <Text style={styles.label}>
        Username: 
      </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" 
        onChangeText={ text => setUsername(text)} value={username} />
      
      <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" onChangeText={ text => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
      />

      <Text style={styles.error}>{message}</Text>
      <Button onPress={ () => log()} title="Login"></Button>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Button onPress={ () => sign()} title="Don't have an acount? Sign up now" />
      </View>
    </View>


  )


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    backgroundColor: '#999',
    
  },
  
  scroll: {
    backgroundColor:'#'
  },

  footer: {
    borderTopColor: '#fff',
    padding:35,
  },

  label: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "white",
    padding: 10,

  },

  input: {
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },


  
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the api response and verified that it is a valid json ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token'<' - react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native)