# Syntax error : JSON parse error : unrecognixed token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, express

Syntax error : JSON parse error : unrecognixed token '<' find solution of this error. one page is working a fine with same code and one page shown this error with same code. i did not understand what is my mistake.

fron end code

```
const getdata = async () => {

try {
  const res = await fetch(`http://192.168.43.220:8000/getuser/${id}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  })

  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data.costomer);
  if (!data) {
    window.alert('error in get data')
  }
  else {
    setdata(data.costomer)
    console.log('data goted by api');
  }

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  window.alert(e)
  window.alert("failed")
}
}
```

and this is back end code

```
app.get('/getuser/:id', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { id } = req.params
    console.log(id);
    const peruserdata = await getschema.findById(id);
    res.status(201).json(peruserdata);
} catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
}

})
```

Comment: that error usually indicates that the server is replying with HTML - check the browser developer tools to see exactly what the server is sending in the response

Comment: or change the data variable to `const data = await res.text();` and then you can see what is returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token'<' - react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837479/json-parse-error-unrecognized-token-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Whether the error occurred at the front end or the back end. It is recommended that you try debugging the data results returned by the back end

Comment: This looks like a comment and not an answer. If you have a question for the original poster, you should leave a comment in the question's thread instead of submitting an answer. Answers should be submitted when you feel you can reasonably solve the original poster's question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from this code:

```
const data = await res.json();
```

You're implying that the `res` can be parsed as JSON but it isn't. What you can do is check the expected HTTP status of the request first before parsing the response.

```
const res = await fetch(...)
if (res.status !== 201) {
    // error handling
}

// parse it here now
const jsonResponse = await res.json()
```